# Can Opportunity Attacks by a mounted PC with the Mounted Combatant feat be made with Advantage?

Tags: dnd-5e, feats, opportunity-attack, advantage-and-disadvantage, mounted-combat

Can Opportunity Attacks have Advantage? For instance, if a character with the *Mounted Combatant* feat was to perform an attack of opportunity on a smaller creature while mounted, would that attack have advantage?

Comment: Also, Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] if you haven't already and see the [help] or ask us here in the comments (use @ to ping someone) if you need more guidance. Good Luck and Happy Gaming!

Answer (score 21):

### Sure

Unless the source of your advantage is dependent on something that doesn't apply to attacks of opportunity (like taking the "Attack Action"), you can absolutely get advantage on an attack of opportunity.

In the case of your specific example, the Mounted Combatant Feat states that (PHB, p. 168):

> You have advantage on melee attack rolls against any unmounted creature that is smaller than your mount.

There's nothing in that description that explicitly rules out an opportunity attack. As long as your opportunity attack fulfilled all the above criteria, it would get advantage.